# Redirect www to non-www and .com to .co.uk and http to https

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to get my domains to redirect to 1 single URL.

I own the .com and .co.uk domain and I want it to be https which I have setup and working.

Target URL - https://exam ple.co.uk

i.e

- http://www.exam ple.co.uk
- http://exam ple.com
- http://www.exam ple.com
- https://www.exam ple.co.uk
- https://exam ple.com
- https://www.exam ple.com

My current config is:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com www.example.co.uk example.co.uk;
    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                          *:443;

    server_name example.co.uk;
}
```

(There is more to my 443 server block but didn't feel this was necessary for this question).

What I have setup currently works for everything except for:

- https://example.com
- ht tps://www.example.com

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks
Rich

Edit:

Full ssl server block.

```
server {
    listen              443;
    server_name         example.co.uk;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";

    access_log          /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example.co.uk.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.co.uk.key;

    ssl_session_timeout     5m;

    ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl on;

            # Increase the proxy buffers for meteor browser-policy.
            proxy_buffer_size       128k;
            proxy_buffers           4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've got it working. Not sure if it the correct way to go about it though.

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com www.example.co.uk example.co.uk;
    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.co.uk.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.co.uk.key;

    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

....
# Then my full ssl server block posted above for example.co.uk
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesn't redirect. When I go to this https:/ /example.com it gives me "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Comment: I've edited the original question and added my ssl server block in.

Answer (score 0):

```
#catches all http requests
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com www.example.co.uk example.co.uk;
    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

#catches https for example.com
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    #ssl setup
    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

#catches https for www.example.co.uk
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.co.uk;
    #ssl setup
    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

#catches https for example.co.uk
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.co.uk;
    #ssl setup
    ...
}
```

This should work.

You must have two separate blocks for the different domains as they will have to return different certificates.

Comment: I did go down this route. Although I didn't have the 3rd server block you have. Regardless. With your answer the page doesn't load. I can see the URL has changed so it looks like the redirect has occurred but I'm now getting - "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Comment: That would indicate that the server block is not set up correctly for ssl. [See here for more information](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create free ssl multidomain certificate with letsencrypt. Read this: https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/server_names.html how nginx searchs server_name and don't worry about duplicate example.co.uk with ~^(www.)?example.*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    liste 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
    server_name  example.co.uk;

    location / {
       root /var/www/app;
    }

}
server {
    listen 80;
    liste 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
    server_name  ~^(www\.)?example.*;
    return 301 https://example.co.uk;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to avoid using a multi-domain cert